# Make a link have 100% width

Tags: css

I have a box that is X px wide. And in it i have a list (`<ul>`) with link elements (`<li><a ..></a><li>`)

How can i with CSS make the link clickable outside the text and in 100% width of the box. Making each line in the box clickable :D

Comment: wrapped the box with the `<a>...</a>`?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Add `display: block` to your `a` element.

Answer (score 29):

I agree with Scott, but I would recommend this code instead:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or this code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="topage" style="display: inline-block">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

I recommend `display: inline-block` because `display: block` makes the `<a>` element appear in its line. (Both will be fine in this case, **but not in all cases**)

**Edit**: It seems that `width:100%` was not referenced. Thanks to @LGSon for commenting out!

Answer (score 6):

To make the link fill out all available space, you can use flexbox:

```
li {
    display: flex;
}
li > a { 
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item {display:flex;} item a {flex:none;}
```